# Worker dial-in pattern with multiple masters?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

There's a worker dial-in pattern described for Akka, particularly here: http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2. It describes a way to fairly spread a load between multiple remote workers. It assumes there's only one master, and workers discover and register with it. Is there a way to support multiple masters with worker dial-in pattern, which supports fair and deterministic sharing of workers between multiple masters?

I imagine the following situation. Let's say there's a cluster with 2 different node roles: front-end and worker. There are multiple front-end nodes which run HTTP servers. Those front-ends delegate the business logic to actors running on worker nodes. The front-ends are behind simple HTTP round-robin load balancer (Nginx).

I'd like to have a shared pool of worker nodes that can be used by any of the front-ends. If one node has more load than other, it should consume more worker nodes' capacity. If the load is too heavy, I should be able to add more worker nodes (probably automatically via auto-scaling), and they should, again, support all of the front-ends fairly, on a need basis.

There is a couple of naive implementation leading to different deficiencies. If workers somehow decide which single front-end to support, then worker capacity might not be spread fairly, because front-end load is highly dynamic. Alternatively, if workers will register with all of the front-ends, there might be a race condition when multiple front-ends request some work from a single worker. All in all, I don't see a good way of supporting this. Has anyone any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

By using clusters current state we can add more than one master

```
   .match(CurrentClusterState.class, state -> {
        for (Member member : state.getMembers()) {
          if (member.status().equals(MemberStatus.up())) {
            register(member);
          }
        }
      })
```